# How to check in router-ui on each state if location is set, if not then go to landing page?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How to implement following scenario in angular router-ui: except the login page user can not browsing the pages without location. Regardless if user is logged in or not, check on each state change if location is set, if not then go to the landing page. If user is logged in and has a location then set a cookie, if not then go to the landing page.

My current concept but it isn't working, whether it is at all the right way?

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngCookies', 'ui.router', 'Devise', 'ngResource']);

app.config([
    '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider' '$cookies', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $cookies) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).state('landing', {
        url: '/landing',
        templateUrl: 'landing.html',
        controller: 'landing',
        resolve: {
            location: [
                '$state ', '$stateParams', '$q', '$window', '$cookies', function ($state, $stateParams, $q, $window, $cookies) {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();

                 $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                    $cookies.location = position;
                    deferred.resolve(position);
                 });
                 return deferred.promise;

            }]
        }
    }).state('login', {
        url: '/login ',
        templateUrl: 'auth/_login.html ',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        onEnter: [
            '$state', 'CustomAuth', function ($state, CustomAuth, $cookies) {
            CustomAuth.currentUserResource().then(function (resp) {
              $cookies.location = resp.data.user.location;
              $state.go('home');
            });
        }]
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);

app.run(function($rootScope, $cookies) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {
    if (!$cookies.location) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('landing');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0ZCVUZTQgpzHyyve7g2?p=preview). We have to do few adjustments.

Firstly, we need to set listener properly. It must NOT redirect, when already recireted

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$cookies',
  function($rootScope, $state, $cookies) { 
  $cookies.location = "";

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState) {

    if(toState.name ===  "landing")
    {
      // already was redirected 
      // we head to landing
      // get out of hee
      return; 
    } 

    if ($cookies.location === "") 
    {

      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('landing'); 
    }
  });

}]);
```

Also, the $cookies is not a provider, it is a service. That means, that we cannot use it in the `.config()` phase, but only in a `.run()` phase.

That means, that it could be injected into `.run()` method, `controller()` or some other service, but not in the `.config()`

Adjusted definition, fixing many minor issues:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .state('landing', {
        url: '/landing',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'landing',
        resolve: {
            location: [
                '$state', '$stateParams', '$q', '$window', '$cookies'
                , function ($state, $stateParams, $q, $window, $cookies) {
                  var deferred = $q.defer();

                  // example how to quickly set some value
                  $cookies.location = "some position";
                  deferred.resolve($cookies.location);                    

                 return deferred.promise;    
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('login', {
        url: '/login ',
        templateUrl: 'tpl.html',
        controller: 'AuthCtrl',
        ...
    })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}])
```

Check the [working example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/w0ZCVUZTQgpzHyyve7g2?p=preview)